# How do I seperate group of numbers which is continuous from matrix?

Tags: arrays, octave

I have a matrix with 3 columns. In the second column I have a continuous number which is having a increment of 2. Suppose in that column a number is missing in between, I want to form a separate group of number which is continuous, and also I have to take the values corresponding to the other two columns.

For example:

```
[1 2  3;
 1 4  6;
 1 6  0;
 1 10 3;
 1 12 6]...
```

In my case order of the matrix is very high so, can you please tell me which loop will work for this and how I can solve this?

Comment: So you want the first three rows of your matrix to be saved separately from the last two in your example? And you use octave as a programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question 100% but I'll give this a shot. You can use the `interp1` function to interpolate data over your missing datapoint. Interp1 can do interpolation in a variety of different ways so take a look at its help file. In the case of the matrix you gave and with linear interpolation I would do the following:

```
A = [1 2  3;
 1 4  6;
 1 6  0;
 1 10 3;
 1 12 6];
index = [min(A(:, 2)) : 2 : max(A(:, 2))]';

B = interp1(A(:,2), A(:, [1 3:end]), index, 'linear');

B = [B(:,1) index B(:,2:end)]

B =

    1.00000    2.00000    3.00000
    1.00000    4.00000    6.00000
    1.00000    6.00000    0.00000
    1.00000    8.00000    1.50000
    1.00000   10.00000    3.00000
    1.00000   12.00000    6.00000
```

Hope this helps!